# Highlight the search result which the cursor is at

Tags: regex, vim

I try to highlight one of search results which the cursor is at, and

I write regex with `matchadd`, `\%#` , `@/`.

But I have no idea about it.

The following is using with substitute.

That's what I want to implement.

[image]

Comment: Not getting a clue on what you are asking!

Comment: What in `:set hlsearch` doesn't work for you?!

Comment: When I type `/highlight`, and all keywords will be highlight with purple color. I want to let one of the results which the cursor is at to be highlight with yellow color.

Comment: You know about `:set incsearch`?! It highlights where the cursor will _jump to_; i.e. the first following match.

Comment: while typing, I can find incsearch highlights the first match. After pressing `enter`, and I press `n` or `N`. I hope that it will always highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will highlight the current search result with the highlight group defined in `s:hl_group`.  It is updated whenever you press `n` or `N`.  It also defines a command `HlClear` to clear the highlight once your are done with it.  This can be called as `:HlClear`.

```
" Set this to a group from :help highlight-default
let s:hl_group = 'ErrorMsg'

function! s:HlNext()
    call s:HlClear()
    let param = getreg('/')
    let s:next_match = matchadd(s:hl_group, '\%#'.param)
    redraw
endfunction

function! s:HlMatch()
    let cmd_type = getcmdtype()
    if cmd_type == '/' || cmd_type == '?'
        return "\<cr>:call ".s:SID()."HlNext()\<cr>"
    endif
    return "\<cr>"
endfunction

function! s:HlClear()
    silent! call matchdelete(s:next_match)
endfunction

function! s:SID()
  return matchstr(expand('<sfile>'), '<SNR>\d\+_\zeSID$')
endfun

nnoremap <silent> n n:call <sid>HlNext()<enter>
nnoremap <silent> N N:call <sid>HlNext()<enter>
cnoremap <silent> <expr> <enter> <sid>HlMatch()

command HlClear :call <sid>HlClear()
```

Comment: Thank you for your patient to read whole of my description, and give me a big help.